# how to show div using it's ID and change the visibility from none to block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need a javascript code that gets a hidden div by Id and changes the style from **display:none;** to **display:block;** .
HTML:

```
<div id="post-author" style="display:none;">by samuel</div>
```

every post in my site has that html code on beginning. how can i be able to print or show element by it's Id ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>document.getElementById("post-author").style.display="block";</script>
```

This will do what you're after :) Just put that in the `head` of your site

Comment: paching off my comments Andy? ;) haha jk. go with this answer @samuel

Comment: haha noooo not at all :P

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered a million times before... but here you go:

```
document.getElementById('post-author').style.display = 'none';
```

and

```
document.getElementById('post-author').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: yes i do know those codes but how to put them in a full script? please, i am a JS newbie ..

Comment: If you don't even know how to put them in a script then you need to learn JavaScript before you even attempt to go any further.

Comment: ok sir i fixed it using CSS which i know, i hope i master this JavaScript one day cause it's better than any other language ..